# How to get difference of dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I was wondering how I can get the difference between two dates in **complete** hours

e.g.

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2011, 8, 5, 33,00); 
long hours = date1 - date2;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the cast to long/int that will give you complete hours.

```
TimeSpan span = date1.Subtract(date2);
long hours = (long)span.TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var hours = (date1 - date2).TotalHours;
```

Or, if you don't want the fraction of an hour:

```
var hours = Math.Floor((date1 - date2).TotalHours);
```

Comment: @saj - What do you consider "complete hours" then? And, by the way, the result of this statement is the exact same as yours (date subtraction in this form results in a TimeSpan as well).

Comment: A full 60 mins, total hours returns a double I would expect no decimals

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) by subtracting both dates:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2011, 8, 5); 
TimeSpan ts = date1 - date2;
long hours = (long)ts.TotalHours;
```

If you want to round it as accurate as possible, you can use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8%28v=vs.100%29):

```
long hours = (long)Math.Round(ts.TotalHours, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
  var result = date1 - date2;
    var hours = result .TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a very nice **[DateTimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216404/444149)** implementation that I use to calculate various differences, hours, days, months [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)