# How to calculate Calendar Number of months between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

I am trying to find calendar number of months between two dates using C#.

Eg1 : dt1 :09-31-2016 
      dt2 : 10-02-2016 
      Result : 2 (1 for September + 1 for October)

Eg2 : dt1 :08-31-2016 
      dt2 : 01-02-2017 
      Result : 6

I am using the below code but not able to achieve the result

```
var difference = ((dt1.Year - dt2.Year) * 12) + (dt1.Month - dt2.Month);
```

Please help me

Comment: Try swapping the dates - looks like you are subtracting the later date from the earlier date

Comment: This is different from the link you have provided

Comment: Seems like you just want to add 1 to the difference.  10 - 9  = 1 but you want 2.

Comment: Thanks Paul & Juhhar. Wanted to see if there is better way than this

Comment: Well [last time this question was posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290776/calculate-the-number-of-calendar-months-between-two-dates) it was closed as a duplicate and I don't see how yours is different. There are [plenty of answers on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates) already.

Answer (score 2):

This should give the answer you want

```
((dt2.Year - dt1.Year) * 12) + (dt2.Month - dt1.Month) + 1
```

Comment: Should actually add 1 to the absolute difference so that it doesn't matter if dt2 > dt1.

Comment: Got it. Thanks PaulF and Juharr :)