# How to know how many times it was the first day of the month in a time frame in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Say I have a timeframe defined by two `DateTime` objects, `d1` and `d2`.

How could I know the number of times the first day of a month is in the timeframe?

Comment: add a sample code to explain your question more

Comment: do you mean for example between 31 Dec 2014 and 23 Mar 2015, how many days which its the first day? ( 01 Jan, 01 Feb, 01 Mar)? 3 times, something like this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in months between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach without the previous bruit force....

---

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 09, 01);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 02, 02);
DateTime loopDate = startDate;
var totalMonths = ((endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) + endDate.Month - startDate.Month;
if (startDate.Day != 1)
{
    loopDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
}

List<DateTime> firstDayOfMonth = Enumerable.Range(0, totalMonths)
    .Select(i => loopDate.AddMonths(i))
    .ToList();

firstDayOfMonth.Add(new DateTime(endDate.Year,endDate.Month, 1));
```

This calculates the months difference based on solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639057/961113). Later it checks if the `startDate` is the first day of month then ignore it, and creates a `loopDate` which would be next available first day of month, and continues till `endDate`.

Here is a working <kbd>.[Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2Krz3)</kbd>

Comment: You forgot to put the line :     DateTime tempStartDate = startDate;

Comment: @razonasistemas, thanks for pointing it out, Modified the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could something like:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100); // {18/11/2014 4:04:07 PM}
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now; // {26/02/2015 4:04:07 PM}
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (endDate - startDate).Days)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
    .Where(r=> r.Day == 1);
```

This will first create a collection of dates from start to end, and later you can filter the results where `Day` part is `1`.

For output:

```
foreach (var dateTime in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

Output:

```
01/12/2014 4:04:07 PM
01/01/2015 4:04:07 PM
01/02/2015 4:04:07 PM
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a way that doesn't require you to enumerate over a collection of dates. Simple arithmetic should do the trick. But it's still a valid answer.

Comment: This is a brute force way to do it.  I worry about the performance of this if I need to calculate all the 1st of the month between Jan 1st 100 to Mar 5 25000

Comment: @thorkia, created [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28753238/961113) which calculates dates from `1-1-1` to `9999-12-31`  in no time.

Comment: @thorkia, only max allowed for `DateTime` in .Net is `9999` year, and this bruit force method would take less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple math.

D1:  Jan 23rd 2015
D2:  Mar 2nd 2015

Find the number of months that have passed (d2.Month - d1.Month).

That gives you the number of first of the months that have passed.

Edge cases you will need to consider:

1. D1 is the first day of the month - just do a simple check for that
   and add 1 to the result
2. D1 and D2 year is different - this is simple as well:
   2.1. Calculate months between D1 and the end of its year (IE: D1 to
   Dec 31st), then make sure to check edge case 1.

   2.2. Calculate the months between D2 and the start of its year (IE: Jan 1st to D2)

   2.3. After that, add 12 for every year difference greater than 1 (it
   means more than one year has passed - D1 is 2010 and D2 is 2013 - 2
   whole years have passed.  Step one caclulated the months in 2010,
   and step 2 for 2013.

   2.4. Add the results of steps 1,2, and 3
   together.

Comment: You don't need to work out months from D1 to the end of the year and from the start to D2. For instance, D1 = 15 Dec 2013; D2 = 20 Jan 2014. (2014-2103)*12 + {Jan - Dec = -11} = 1.