# convert number of days into years,months,days

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datediff, days

I need to convert the number of days into years, months, days.

Example: A Employee Experience to be calculated as per his Date of `join(DOJ)` and date of `Relieve(DOR)`. We have a `DOJ, DOR and Number` of Days he is worked as a employee.

Have to Calculate the How many Years and Months and Days.

```
Example       : DOJ = 14 Feb 2000
                DOR = 08 aug 2013
Output        : 13 Years - 5 Months - 25 Days
```

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: `DOJ` and `DOR` are `DateTime`?

Comment: I've seen year-days or year-months conversion, they are easier to implement. For year-month-day, prob play around with timespan I guess :p

Comment: @RyanChu I already tried it... not useful.. Thank you for your Interest...

Comment: If you have already tried the Timespan, show us what you have tried and what about it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var dor = new DateTime(2013, 08, 08);
var doj = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14);

var totalmonths = (dor.Year - doj.Year) * 12 + dor.Month - doj.Month;
totalmonths += dor.Day < doj.Day ? -1 : 0;

var years = totalmonths / 12;
var months = totalmonths % 12;
var days = dor.Subtract(doj.AddMonths(totalmonths)).Days;
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, it does. `f = new DateTime(2004, 2, 14), t = new DateTime(2004, 3, 13)` => 28 days. `f = new DateTime(2005, 2, 14), t = new DateTime(2005, 3, 13)` => 27 days.

Comment: Sorry, in fact I wonder if this is after all equivalent to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9216404/134204) answer that counts years etc from start to end, only much shorter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - There is a bug in the code that you linked too. Try running that code with the dates 2020-02-29 to 2021-06-29 - it returns "1y 4m 1d", when it should be "1y 4m 0d" (which my code returns). The bug in that code appears to be due to the understanding of how `.AddMonths(1)` works when applied to `2015-01-30` - it returns `2015-02-28`. So the calc ends up being short a few days.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a number of days into years months and days because you don't know where those days lie. For example they may span 29th Feb on a leap year.

However you already have the two dates to work with so you can calculate this value like so:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

    Dim doj As Date = New Date(2000, 2, 14)
    Dim dor As Date = New Date(2013, 8, 8)

    MessageBox.Show(GetDateSpanText(doj, dor))

End Sub

Public Shared Function GetDateSpanText(fromDate As DateTime, Optional toDate As DateTime = Nothing) As String
    Try
        Dim years As Integer = 0, months As Integer = 0, days As Integer = 0
        If toDate = Nothing Then toDate = DateTime.Now

        Do Until toDate.AddYears(-1) < fromDate
            years += 1
            toDate = toDate.AddYears(-1)
        Loop

        Do Until toDate.AddMonths(-1) < fromDate
            months += 1
            toDate = toDate.AddMonths(-1)
        Loop

        Do Until toDate.AddDays(-1) < fromDate
            days += 1
            toDate = toDate.AddDays(-1)
        Loop

        Return String.Format("{0} Years {1} Months {2} Days", years, months, days)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Error"
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, you can by asking the [System.Globalization.Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  class. You don't need to though, as you *can* calculate the difference between for the year and month parts. The leftover, days, can be calculated as a TimeSpan. This is shown in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9216404/134204)

Answer (score 0):

You may use for Years and Months calculation from months, If you have 30 months then it will return 2 Years and 6 Months by using following code.

> Math.Round((double)Months/12,0) Years and  Month%12 Months