# How calculate if a Date is 6 month later birthdate in C#

Tags: c#

how can I calculate if a date (in DateTime format) is 6 month later or not from my BirthDate (in DateTime format)?

Comment: Do you mean birthdate, or birthday? (i.e. do you want to know if a particular date is exactly 6 months after you were born, or 6 months after any of your birthdays?)

Comment: Please reread your question, it's really not clear what's the problem and what's expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter your birth date, calculate your next birthday and compare the dates,

```
        var born = new DateTime(1900, 02, 01);
        var checkdate = DateTime.Now;


        var nextBirthday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, born.Month, born.Day);
        if (nextBirthday < DateTime.Now)
        {
            nextBirthday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, born.Month, born.Day);
        }

        if (checkdate.AddMonths(6) < nextBirthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("date is 6 months later then birthday");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wait for it");
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `DateTime` `AddMonth` method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var dat = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);
var dat2 = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);

if (dat.AddMonths(6) < dat2) { ... }
```

Comment: dat.AddMonths(6) like this doesn't really do anything, as it RETURNS the date + 6 months, it doesn't actually change "dat".

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) :

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime birthDate;

if (dt <= birthDate.AddMonths(6))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime birthDate=new DateTime(year,month,day);
DateTime dateToCompare = new DateTime(year, month, day);

if(dateToCompare >= birthdate.AddMonths(6))
{
   //DoSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculte the difference between dates using `Subtract` method and calculate how many months you have between these dates, for sample:

```
DateTime birthDay = /* some date */;
DateTime someDate = /* some date */;

var months = someDate.Subtract(birthDay).Days / (365.25 / 12);
```

This answer provides a good helper for Dates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33287670/316799