# Asp.net Months doesnt give me proper value

Tags: asp.net

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime dTDoJ = DateTime.ParseExact("07/01/2017", "MM/dd/yyyy", ci);
int months = Math.Abs((DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month - dTDoJ.Month) + 12 * (DateTime.Now.Year - dTDoJ.Year));
```

Instead of 6 months it gives me 17 months

Answer (score 0):

Well, `DateTime.Now.Year` is `2018`, and `dToJ.Year` is `2017`. So the difference is going to be `1` which places the difference to at least `12`. 
The `5` comes from the first term, which is basically `12 - 7`, which is `5`. Adding them together gets you `17`.

If you can get by with [Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates) for an accurate answer. It's very similar to your formula.