# VB Code to C# - Namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

I am converting VB Code to C#. Following is the Code.

```
CrByMonthCr = Val(DateDiff("m", StartDate, DateSerial(Year(EndDate), Month(EndDate), 1)) + 1) * MonthCr
```

In C# code I imported namespace - `using Microsoft.VisualBasic`.
I only managed to settle `DateDiff` function. `Val` & `DateSerial` are giving compiler error.

```
CrByMonthCr = Val(DateAndTime.DateDiff("m", StartDate, DateSerial(Year(EndDate), Month(EndDate), 1)) + 1) * MonthCr
```

Does any one know why inspite of importing namespace of VisualBasic it is giving errors? How to solve this?

> DateSerial does not exists in the current context

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: error - DateSerial does not exists in the current context

Comment: A lot of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` functionality (certainly the stuff for .NET version 1, before all of the `My` stuff got added) was effectively put in to minimize conversion between VB 6 and VB.Net. The only reason to keep using that functionality is if you're trying to stay bug-for-bug compatible with some pre-.NET VB code. If not, I'd recommend that now is the time to explore what each function does and then identify the *standard* way of achieving that using normal, non-VB framework classes.

Comment: I have to agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. The first thing you should do is modify you VB code to remove all that VB-specific code. Once it's all standard .NET code then converting it to C# will be simple.

Comment: this is the difference of 2 months in disguide - see this post on the subject - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

[`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateserial?view=netframework-4.7.2) exist in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime?view=netframework-4.7.2) class as a static method, so to keep using it you need `DateAndTime.DateSerial(Year(EndDate), Month(EndDate), 1)`.
But you can simply replace it with [`new DateTime(EndDate.Year, EndDate.Month, 1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: I suggest you change your answer a bit because Anup is asking to convert. Based on this, I believe your second answer is the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Zohar Peled `DateSerial` is member of `DateAndTime`.
`Val` is member of `Conversion`. So the full code (with `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`) is

```cs
CrByMonthCr = Conversion.Val(DateAndTime.DateDiff("m", StartDate, DateAndTime.DateSerial(DateAndTime.Year(EndDate), DateAndTime.Month(EndDate), 1)) + 1) * MonthCr;
```