# How To get Interval Between Two Datetime (Timestamp)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I organized a program which started on 31st December 2018 at 10:00pm hence its been four months ago, i want a way to find this duration by code.

for example , how youtube is able to tell when a comment was written(eg,4years ago,5 months ago).

Comment: You are looking for [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What should happen to this calculation if you stop and restart the program? Do you want to know the uptime from the last start of your program?

Comment: maybe this is what you should be looking at. This SO question looks for duration in years, months, days etc. just how you have given the example of youtube.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

You can simply substract a `DateTime` object from another, which results in a `TimeSpan` representing the difference:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
DateTime y = DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan difference = x - y;
```

Comment: Heck, you beat me by ~3 seconds :'D

Answer (score 1):

```
        var programStartDateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
        var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - programStartDateTime;
        Console.WriteLine($"The difference is: {timeSpan.ToString()}");
```

Comment: You are missing the time part (10:00)

Answer (score 0):

I think below sample code may help you

```
  DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  TimeSpan time = date1 - date2;
  WriteLine($"TimeSpan : {time}" );
```