# How do I find the age of a vehicle in months c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day)
>   [Difference in months between two dates (C#, .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-c-net)

Hi
I'm a novice at c# and I need to find out the age of a vehicle in months when I enter a date of registration. I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: It is ambiguous, the number of days in a month isn't fixed.  You will also have to tell us what should happen when the vehicle was purchased on Feb 29th of a leap year.

Comment: As above, If the vehicle was purchased on Feb 29th, on the 1st of march it would be considered 1 mth old. I just need to count the months that have elapsed since it was first registered. If the date has entered, say january the 1st, then January will be counted as 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

See > [Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-c-net)

This is even better > [How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day/1083991#1083991)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get the days, but how mamy months that is is up for discussion.

The following code uses the average 30.4 (365/12) days/month .

```
TimeSpan age = DateTime.ToDay - RegistrationDate;

double months1 = age.TotalDays / 30.4;

int months = (int) months1;
```

But some business systems will have their own rules, maybe from 2011-04-30   to 2011-05-01 will count as 1 month. You need a good definition.

Comment: Well, this only accumulates errors from leap years after 120 years. That's probably not relevant to the OP, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

A very crude way of doing it would be, simply subtracting the registration date from the current time, and get the total months from the number of days:

```
TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - registrationDate;
int months = (int) (age.TotalDays/30);
```

After a few years (about six or seven) you'll get extra months counted. Counting in months is not easy because a month is not an exact quantity. I'm guessing that a vehicle being six years old is probably very common, so this may not be a good fit.

A better alternative would be to subtract the years and the months directly:

```
int fullYears = (now.Year - registrationDate.Year) * 12;
int partialYear = now.Month - registrationDate.Month;
int months = fullYears + partialYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `(DateTime.Now - registrationDate).TotalDays / 31` (or `30`, depending on how you define months)

Comment: The OP wants months, not days.

Comment: `TimeSpan` doesn't have a Months property.

Comment: I think you got really confused here SLaks. Months/31 would not do anything meaningful. Not even days like Henk says (days would be Months*31).

Comment: Yes, I did get really confused here.  I knew that there was no `Months` property, but I got mixed up when writing the code. Sorry about that.