# Calculate difference between two dates in form `X years, Y months, Z week, A day`

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day)

How do i calculate exact difference between to date including years, days, moths, weeks. Just like windows calculator does. ?

And represent like this `1 years, 1 months, 1 week, 1 day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built into .NET itself which does this in a useful way. `TimeSpan` (which you'd get from `date2 - date1`) doesn't have the concept of months etc - it's just a duration in ticks, effectively.

You can use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) for this, but it's not quite finished yet. The period calcuation part may well change further... I'm not sure yet. Let me know if you'd like a Noda Time code sample.

Also be aware that arithmetic using dates is [fundamentally tricky](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx). Sometimes it's hard to work out what the right answer should even be...

Comment: I'm getting 404 error while opening `http://noda-time.sourceforge.net/`

Comment: @Neeraj: Gah, sorry, it's too early for me. I've fixed the link :)

Comment: @Jon: you may need to repeat your answer you have provided here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
TimeSpan span = endDate - startDate;
//span.TotalDays gives days
```

As for months, years and weeks one would like to know whether you need a `Math.Floor` or `Math.Ceil`

Comment: As per my comment on Peter's answer, that won't help for weeks, months and years.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: if i knew you were around, I wouldn't have even answered :) I just started on getting years and then i realized the complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on MSDN
For your case you can use the first method `System.TimeSpan` to get the differnce in the specified format.

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);
System.DateTime date3 = new System.DateTime(1996, 10, 12, 8, 42, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);

// date4 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date4 = date3.Subtract(diff1);

// diff2 gets 55 days 4 hours and 20 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date2 - date3;

// date5 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date5 = date1 - diff2;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=VS.80).aspx#Y913