# NodaTime usage for datetimepicker

Tags: winforms, datetimepicker, c#-5.0, nodatime

To avoid label of **duplicate** here's a brief summary of all what i did.

After spending hours of googling to calculate the difference between two dates  I came across [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639570/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-form-x-years-y-months-z-week-a-day) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day) where, i was convinced to use [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/N_NodaTime.htm) to get difference in terms of years,months and days.My application needs accuracy to calculate pension.I used `datetimepicker` to get the date value from form and then i use `Date.cs` from [here](https://github.com/claycephas/csharp-date/blob/master/CSharpDate/Date.cs) to extract the date in `dd/mm/year` and then insert it into database.To subtract the two dates using `Period.Between(date1, date2, PeriodUnits.Years).Years` how should i pass `datetimepicker` to it?

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476817/how-to-accurately-get-difference-between-two-datetime-object-in-years-closed) what Jon Skeet said: "you can use `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime` and then use the `Date` property to get a `LocalDate`".

How should i get a complete rid of time while inserting in database as well as finding the difference while using `datetimepicker` instead of `Datetime`.

**Update:**

```
//Date of appointment
var d_app = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value).Date;
//Date of retirement
var d_ret = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value).Date;
var years=Period.Between(d_app,d_ret,PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
var months = Period.Between(d_app, d_ret, PeriodUnits.Months).Months;
var days = Period.Between(d_app, d_ret, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
MessageBox.Show(years.ToString()+" years"+months.ToString()+"months "+days.ToString()+"days");
```

Giving the code `datetimepicker1.value` as `2/21/1990` (d_app) and `datetimepicker2.value` as `3/09/2015`(d_ret) it returned `25 yrs 300months 9147
 days`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what you're seeing - but that's clearly not valid code given that "DateTime datetimepicker.Days.ToString" isn't even slightly valid as a method argument. There's no need to use that other `Date` code, either. Why are you calling `Days`? Why are you referring to `ToString`?

Comment: Please note that using @JonSkeet for a question I haven't seen before doesn't do anything, btw.

Comment: It looks like you just want `var dateOfBirth = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimePicker.Value).Date;`

Comment: Sorry if u mind for explicit mentioning but i bet u knew answer :)
Using `Days.ToString` was the only meaningful option for the purpose provided by Intellisense.

Comment: You misunderstood me - my point is that the explicit mention didn't do anything, because it wasn't in reply to something I'd written.

Comment: *Please* put more effort into formatting code in future. It makes a huge difference in readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing three *separate* computations here. You only need one:

```
var appointment = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value).Date;
var retirement = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value).Date;
var difference = Period.Between(appointment, retirement);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} years {1} months {2} days",
   difference.Years, difference.Months, difference.Days));
```

Comment: Not going for `Date.cs` would i be able to get `mm/dd/year` using `NodaTime` for database insertion?

Comment: @CrystalHeart: It's not clear what you mean, but you shouldn't be inserting into the database using *strings* at all. You'll probably want to convert back to `DateTime`, and set the parameter value in your SQL command that way.

Comment: What if i don't show the `time` and insert into database the date as string for `listview` things?

Comment: Something like  `Command.Parameters.Add("@appintment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = app_date.ToShortString();` where `ToShortString` were serving `mm/dd/yyyy` taken from `Date.cs`

Comment: @CrystalHeart: I have no idea what you mean by that, but fundamentally if you're trying to store a date or a date/time value, you should make the database schema reflect that, and use the appropriate type of parameter when inserting. Why would you use varchar to represent a date? It's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Do u consider it important for a date having time specified in a `listview` to user with `appointment`.If no,then how can i insert _only_ date in database

Comment: @CrystalHeart: Sorry, your comments *really* don't make any sense to me. If you only want a date in the database, use a column type of Date. If you want a date and time, use DateTime. I don't see where list views come into that decision. It sounds like you should probably ask a new question though, because we're now a long way from your original question.

Comment: Using column of `Date` type to insert a date also adds a `12:00 AM` to each date which i want to get rid of.Now how would you avoid this ?

Comment: @CrystalHeart: What do you mean by "adds a 12:00 AM to each date"? Do you mean when you fetch it as a `DateTime`? That's just because `DateTime` doesn't have the concept of "just a date". To avoid that, use `LocalDate` in Noda Time instead...

Comment: Would you mind giving a method of Noda Time which formats time in "mm/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: @CrystalHeart: Have you read the user guide about text formatting? http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/text.html Then look at [`LocalDatePattern`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/AllMembers_T_NodaTime_Text_LocalDatePattern.htm)

Comment: @CrystalHeart: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. But at this point we're quite a long way from your original question. I suggest you ask a new question if you're stuck - complete with what you've tried, etc.

Comment: I just needed a method of noda time to replace `Date.cs` which Parses the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

Comment: @CrystalHeart: Right, so that's not the same as this question, which is about computing period differences - so ask a new question, after doing some research.