# How can I get the count in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have table called `products` with columns:

```
productid ,
productname,
productprice
categoryid
```

My problem is I want to get the number of products depending on product name along with details.  I want to show the data in `DataGridView`. How can I know the number of products for a single product name like below?

```
productid        productname          productavailable        productprice
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                product A            2 products(product A)   100
2                product B            5 Products(product B)   200
```

Like the above table I have to display in `DataGridView`. I am using LINQ and C# and my `DbContext` name is `tsgdbcontext`.

Comment: Are you really using entity-framework and linq-to-sql at the same time? They are two different frameworks from MS.

Comment: Question is a little confusing, is "productavailable" a column in your products table? Is it a count?

Comment: @marr75 productavaialable not a column in database but it is column in datagrid view for finding the number of products......

Comment: He can use linq and entity framework at the same time... LINQ != LINQ to SQL. LINQ is just the set of extensions to the framework.

Comment: @xanatos I am sorry I am using entity framework unexpectedly i have tagged linq-to-sql ...

Comment: Seems like you need to add a column that tracks the count of products available to the database then. I don't know how we would tell you where your own data is.

Comment: @xanatos Oh I see, you meant the tags, not the question. Good find.

Comment: @marr75 my problem is how can i find the number of products depends upon the product name and product id ...how can i calculate using entities...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` with a key that contains your grouping properties.  Then `select` out the key properties along with the count of each from the grouping.

```
var query = tsgdbcontext.Products
                        .GroupBy(p => new {
                            p.ProductId,
                            p.ProductName,
                            p.ProductPrice
                         })
                        .Select(g => new {
                            g.Key.ProductId,
                            g.Key.ProductName,
                            g.Key.ProductPrice,
                            Available = g.Count()
                        });
```

Comment: one request would you pls take  a look at this question , i have tried but dint get any idea how to do this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370839/how-can-i-get-the-membership-sold-count

Answer (score 30):

Not sure I am understanding exactly + making some assumptions but here is an example linq  query that produces a count based on some arbitrary selection criteria (id=2 and price greater than 100)...

```
int count = (from p in tsgdbcontext.Products
             where p.productid == 2 && p.productprice > 100
             select p).Count();
```

Comment: Doesn't this retrieve the whole dataset from the DB as apposed to a dedicated COUNT expression that only gets the number of elements from the DB?

Comment: @Oszkar No, it doesn't. `COUNT(1)` will be added to the query sent to the DB.

Comment: What if no Products are available, does this return 0 or does it throw a null exception?

Comment: Presuming that `Products` itself is not null then no (empty is fine). If `Products` contains null values then it would throw inside the `where` when p is null and `p.productid` is accessed.

Comment: Yes, I've just tested, it returns 0. But `.Sum()` of empty list throws exception.