# How to select count value by linq

Tags: linq

I want express sql below by linq

```
select catalog,queryname,COUNT(*) from doctemplatecells group by catalog,queryname
```

I don't know how to get count(*), thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372805/how-can-i-get-the-count-in-linq

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i get the count in linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372805/how-can-i-get-the-count-in-linq)

Answer (score 2):

Every group consists of it's key (catalog, queryname) and it's elements as represented by the `IEnumerable<>` implementation of the group.

So if you have a group as a result of LinQ, you can call the extension method `Count()` on it.

```
var groups =  doctemplatecells.GroupBy(dtc => new { Catalog = dtc.catalog, QueryName = dtc queryname });

foreach(group in groups)
{
    console.WriteLine("{0} {1} #{2}", group.Key.Catalog, group.Key.QueryName, group.Count());
}
```