# Difference between two dates in Vb.net (0 YEAR, 0 MONTHS, 0 DAYS LEFT)

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day)

I have a problem with the difference between two dates.
I need the out put in `0 YEAR, 0 MONTHS, 0 DAYS LEFT`m e.g.:

```
 1 YEAR, 2 MONTHS, 3 DAYS LEFT
```

With dateDiff function or using anything else it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime as the representation you can have something like:

```
  dim test as DateTime = DateTime.Now
  dim test2 as DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
  dim result as TimeSpan = test.Subtract(test2)
  dim hours as Integer = result.Hours
  dim days as Integer = result.Days
  int years=days mod 365
  days=days-years*365
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    ' A Start date an end Date to test with
    Dim StartingDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim TargetEndDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).AddDays(5).AddMinutes(45)

    ' Get the difference between the two dates, and Create a new Date containing just the total days
    Dim DifferenceBetweenDates As TimeSpan = TargetEndDate.Subtract(StartingDate)
    Dim DiffFromSystemDate As New DateTime(0, 0, DifferenceBetweenDates.TotalDays)

    ' Get the number of years, months and days left
    Dim NumberOfYears As Integer = DiffFromSystemDate.Year - 1
    Dim NumberOfMonths As Integer = DiffFromSystemDate.Month - 1
    Dim NumberOfDays As Integer = StartingDate.Day - DateTime.DaysInMonth(StartingDate.Year, StartingDate.Month)

    ' Build up the result string
    Dim Result As String = String.Format("{0} YEAR, {1} MONTHS, {3} DAYS LEFT", NumberOfYears, NumberOfMonths, NumberOfDays)
```

1. I haven't compiled it yet
2. It doesn't fully work (leap years, and days of the year)

Please see JonSkeets post in the duplicate for a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues sometime back and found one solution.
Just remember d1 is endDate and d2 is startDate. d1 > d2

```
public static void TimeSpanToDate(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, out int years, out int months, out int days)
{
    // compute & return the difference of two dates,
    // returning years, months & days
    // d1 should be the larger (newest) of the two dates
    // we want d1 to be the larger (newest) date
    // flip if we need to
    if (d1 < d2)
    {
        DateTime d3 = d2;
        d2 = d1;
        d1 = d3;
    }

    // compute difference in total months
    months = 12 * (d1.Year - d2.Year) + (d1.Month - d2.Month);

    // based upon the 'days',
    // adjust months & compute actual days difference
    if (d1.Day < d2.Day)
    {
        months--;
        days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d2.Year, d2.Month) - d2.Day + d1.Day;
    }
    else
    {
        days = d1.Day - d2.Day;
    }
    // compute years & actual months
    years = months / 12;
    months -= years * 12;
}
```

it works fine for me.

Hope it helps.

Praveen