# There are 52.17 weeks in a year. How do I compute current week in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am saving data into a circular log with designated byte multiples (dataSlots), and I'm calculating the week number based on the days that pass from a reference date.

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
 for (int ii = 0; ii < 900; ii++)
 {
    currentDate = startDate + new TimeSpan(7 * ii, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    DateTime globalStartReference = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var span = currentDate - globalStartReference ;
    int dataSlot = 0;
    dataSlot = (span.Days * 7) / 52;
    Console.WriteLine(dataSlot);
 }
```

My hope is that dataSlot will be an ever-increasing number based upon the current week, however it isn't.  I get duplicate entries (and therefore overwrite my data) on these weeks

```
11
28
44
60
77
88
109
```

Why am I getting duplicate weeks and how do I account for this?  My guess is that there is a fractional number of weeks in a year...

Answer (score 5):

The [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) may be helpful.  It doesn't allow for an arbitrary reference date, however you could adjust for that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the current week for any given year?  It looks like from some pre-defined start date ad infinitum.  Using the appropriate calendar, and methods it it, you can get a given week of the year based on a particular date, but not x weeks from any arbitrary date.

Plus you need to account for leap years, partial weeks, etc.

Comment: What methods are available to determine week of year?  I don't see them under DateTime.   I need to get the sum of all weeks from a given start date (fixed, system defined or not), to a user supplied end date.

Comment: Well, it would probably involve the Calendar class... but have you also checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day

Answer (score 0):

If you're just worried about weeks from baseline, years don't enter into it - it's just 7-day increments.

Otherwise you have year and week-of-year; @BACON's answer is probably right for this. You'll get a bit of overlap - Y2W1 may share the same calendar week as Y1W52.  Dunno if you'll just add and make that Week 53 but this gets problematic the longer you go.